# How to change the position of a Linked Object?

Tags: objects, linked-data, append

I've made multiple blendfiles with objects, curves and materials. Now I want to place these 'element'-blendfiles in one 'parent'-blendfile; building one scene to render. Because I am going to build multiple 'parent'-blendfiles I thought of linking the element-files onto the parent-files. But now I noticed I cannot move the objects around in the 'parent'-files; because they're linked and cannot be edited.

Is there a way to give the linked objects a custom position in these 'parent'-files?